# Elasticsearch disk is enough, but there is an error: all indexes on this node will be marked read-only

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, centos7, elasticsearch-6.5

I checked that the disk was available enough, but es still gave a warning and the data could not be read;

Warning: all indications on this node will be marked read only

What can I do to avoid this problem and stabilize the system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRhnq.png)

Comment: Can you show the exact error from the log?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63920579/how-to-mount-my-es-data-folder-to-freed-filesystem-in-mac-os is your issue is similar to this one?

Comment: The following is the partial es log:[2020-10-12T03:49:45,785][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [UZZr1MW] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [UZZr1MWARDuDEqmy6gGzHw][UZZr1MW][/home/centos/elasticsearch-6.4.1/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[1%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
[2020-10-12T03:50:15,806][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [UZZr1MW] rerouting shards: [one or more nodes has gone under the high or low watermark]

Comment: Could you please check the directory where your elasticsearch stores its data? you can find this in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml . In my view your are storing data in wrong directory.